# Why does :before don't push down elements below on IE?

Tags: html, css

This is driving me nuts. Im displaying a banner trough css and :the before selector on a website where I cant access the html, which works great on all browsers except IE, where it floats above elements below. I ant figure out for the world why? It does push the elements down on the frontpage though.  Example: http://shop.xeptor.se/products/Computers/Desktops
This seems to apply to IE8,9,10 on Win 8 and 7 as fars as I can see trough simulation.

Edit: Seems to be the same problem on Safari.

Css:

```
contentbar:before {
 z-index: 100000;
top: -20px;
content:url('http://infotheek.com/images/xeptor/Large_banner_microsoft.jpg');
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: "IE" is rather vague. Which version?

Comment: Which version of IE?  Each version is a *completely* separate browser.

Comment: Also, shouldn't that be `contentbar::before{` (with 2 colons)?

Comment: No, I need IE8 support aswell, so Im using single colons. @Rocket Hazmat

Comment: All of them.. @TiesonT.

Comment: You should try displaying it as `inline-block` with a `width`, `height` and `background-image`. Use `content: ' ';`. That always works for getting more control over `:before`s and `:after`s as they act more like predictable blocks...

Comment: Om my god. Display: block solved it. How could I have missed that.. Would have been a lot easier with some good IE inspector tools.. And a pc!   And thanks for the pointers!